# For display only product

Tags: products, product-list

I have a product that is automatically added to the cart for those customers who are entitled to order it.

The customer can not add the product to cart herself.

However, we want the product to be visible in the product catalog, so the customer can see all the product images and information. However, there must not be price of the product visible and the add to cart button must be hidden.

How can I accomplish this?

If you a good extension to implement this, that would also be an option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this with a [layout update.](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/3103/remove-add-to-cart-button-for-some-products) 
In the admin, inside the product go to Design > Custom Layout XML and add:

```
<reference name="content">
  <remove name="product.info.addtocart"/>
</reference>
```

Same goes for price, I can't find the code snippet right now, will edit once I find it.

Comment: Nice! How about price and hiding the same in catalog?